# How do I bind a Byte array to an Image in WPF with a value converter?

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, xaml, image

I'm trying to bind a Byte array from my databse to a WPF Image.

My XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BinaryImageConverter x:Key="imgConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageData, Converter={StaticResource imgConverter}}" />
```

I've modified code published by [Ryan Cromwell](http://cromwellhaus.com/blogs/ryanc/archive/2007/07/26/binding-to-the-byte-of-an-image-in-wpf.aspx) for a value converter:

```
Class BinaryImageConverter
    Implements IValueConverter
    Private Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        If value IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf value Is Byte() Then
            Dim bytes As Byte() = TryCast(value, Byte())
            Dim stream As New MemoryStream(bytes)
            Dim image As New BitmapImage()
            image.BeginInit()
            image.StreamSource = stream
            image.EndInit()
            Return image
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
    Private Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.")
    End Function
End Class
```

The i`mage.EndInit()` line of the BinaryImageConverter's Convert() function throws this **NotSupportedException**:

> "No imaging component suitable to
>   complete this operation was found."
>
> InnerException: "Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x88982F50"

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  How can I get this working?

---

### Update

It seems the problem was the bytes coming out of the database.  There must have been a problem with the way I was putting them in.

See my working code below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks for all your help.  I've now got it working.  I'm still not sure exactly what the problem was.

This is how I put images into my database…

```
Private Sub ButtonUpload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim FileOpenStream As Stream = Nothing
    Dim FileBox As New Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog()
    FileBox.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures)
    FileBox.Filter = "Pictures (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png|" & _
                     "All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    FileBox.FilterIndex = 1
    FileBox.Multiselect = False
    Dim FileSelected As Nullable(Of Boolean) = FileBox.ShowDialog(Me)
    If FileSelected IsNot Nothing AndAlso FileSelected.Value = True Then
        Try
            FileOpenStream = FileBox.OpenFile()
            If (FileOpenStream IsNot Nothing) Then

                Dim ByteArray As Byte()
                Using br As New BinaryReader(FileOpenStream)
                    ByteArray = br.ReadBytes(FileOpenStream.Length)
                End Using

                Dim g As New ZackGraphic
                g.Id = Guid.NewGuid
                g.ImageData = ByteArray
                g.FileSize = CInt(ByteArray.Length)
                g.FileName = FileBox.FileName.Split("\").Last
                g.FileExtension = "." + FileBox.FileName.Split(".").Last.ToLower
                g.DateAdded = Now

                Dim bmp As New BitmapImage
                bmp.BeginInit()
                bmp.StreamSource = New MemoryStream(ByteArray)
                bmp.EndInit()
                bmp.Freeze()

                g.PixelWidth = bmp.PixelWidth
                g.PixelHeight = bmp.PixelHeight

                db.AddToZackGraphic(g)
                db.SaveChanges()

            End If
        Catch Ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. " & Ex.Message, "Add a New Image", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error, MessageBoxResult.OK)
        Finally
            If (FileOpenStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                FileOpenStream.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

This is my value converter used to bind a Byte array to an Image…

```
Class BinaryImageConverter
    Implements IValueConverter
    Private Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        If value IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf value Is Byte() Then
            Dim ByteArray As Byte() = TryCast(value, Byte())
            Dim bmp As New BitmapImage()
            bmp.BeginInit()
            bmp.StreamSource = New MemoryStream(ByteArray)
            bmp.EndInit()
            Return bmp
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
    Private Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.")
    End Function
End Class
```

This is my XAML that uses the converter display the image…

```
<Window xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProjectName" ... >
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BinaryImageConverter x:Key="imgConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
...
<Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageData, Converter={StaticResource imgConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 32):

You **can** bind a byte[] to an Image.

Here a Sample:

Xaml:

```
<Image Source="{Binding UserImage}"/>
```

Code:

```
private byte[] userImage;

public byte[] UserImage
   {
       get { return userImage; }
       set
       {
           if (value != userImage)
           {
               userImage = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("UserImage");
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: I tried your solution. But I get an error like `Can't convert type System.Byte[] to type System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`

Comment: Probably, because I am developing for Windows phone.

Comment: Not sure about 2013, but on .NET 4.5 binding `byte[]` directly to `Image` works just fine

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is actually a security permission issue. Try running with administrator privileges, and see if that works, and go from there.

EDIT: I disagree with the downvote and comment. Take a look at this link:

http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/617f6711-0373-44cc-b72c-aeae20f0f7a8/

This user had the exact same error, and it was caused by security settings. Therefore, I stand by my answer (which may not be the cause, but it is certainly worth a try)

Answer (score 2):

Try using this

```
Dim imageSource as ImageSource
Dim bitmapDecoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
imageSource = bitmapDecoder.Frames[0];
imageSource.Freeze();
Return imageSource
```

Comment: This throws the same exception on the "Dim bitmapDecoder = " line.

Comment: If you save the image directly to a FileStream does it open successfully?

Comment: Additionally, in your update you're reading the image from a a stream and then putting that image object's data into the database.  why not just load the FileOpenStream directly into the database?

Comment: bendewey, I changed my ButtonUpload_Click() method to "Using br As New BinaryReader(FileOpenStream)" and re-added the image to the database with that method.  I still get the same exception.

Comment: what about saving it to disk directly from the database?

Comment: This creates a 24,425 byte file that cannot be read by Windows Picture and Fax Viewer.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the bytes are not a legitimate image format.  I believe that error code corresponds to `WINCODEC_ERR_COMPONENTNOTFOUND`, which would be consistent with invalid bytes.

What format is the byte array supposed to be in?  Can you save it to disk, and try to open it with another imaging program?

Comment: This creates a 24,425 byte file that cannot be read by Windows Picture and Fax Viewer.

Comment: @Zack: Then that means that my answer was correct, you have an invalid format for the image file (either that, or the way you are getting/processing the bytes is incorrect and corrupting it).