# Create bitmap/image from 3 byte array (channels)

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, bitmap

Is it possbile to create a WPF Bitmap/Image from three seperate byte arrays (channels)?

What i can do is to merge the 3 byte channels into 1 int array and use one of the create bitmap/image methods.

But i want to avoid to merge all the byte-Data Pixel by Pixel.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could try a Converter to handle all three. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686461/how-do-i-bind-a-byte-array-to-an-image-in-wpf-with-a-value-converter)

Comment: Seems not to be that what i want to achieve. Lets assume we have 3 arrays byte[] r, byte[] g, byte[] b. Now i want to have something like (Pseudocode: BitmapSource.Create(r,g,b) )