# WPF C# displaying image at XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

There are many example or source code on converting `byte[]` to `Bitmap` but I'm not sure on how to show or bind at my view `xaml`.

My convert function as below:

```
private Bitmap ConvertByteToBitmap(byte[] bmpByte)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (Bitmap)converter.ConvertFrom(bmpByte);
}
```

Says I have 10 users and user object has **photo** variable which is `byte[]` type. 
Now I'm wondering on how to bind the converted `byte[]` to `image` tag and display them in grid at `xaml`? Should I create another variable to store the converted image result to bind at `xaml`?

For example:

**UserObject**:

- **Name**: Jane

- **Photo**: 0x0023347dgas83.....

- **Name**: Isaac

- **Photo**: 0x1023347ddffeas83.....

Normally bind Text at `textbox` like

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding [someviewmodel].UserObject.Name}"/>
```

**What about the way to bind the bitmap image**?

Comment: Have property of type `BitmapImage` and `BitmapSource` in your viewmodel and bind with that.

Comment: @RohitVats: So I need to convert each and every `byte[]` and store each of them into a variable of their respective object?

Comment: If that's the case, do not create duplicate copies. Instead write a converter which will convert `byte[]` to `BitmapImage`. You can refer for converter code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/687161/632337).

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
public class MyItem
{
    private readonly byte[] _image;

    ...

    public byte[] Image { get { return _image; } }

}
```

and then in XAML for example:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[`ImageSourceConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesourceconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does all the conversion for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new variable.
If you know the dimensions of the picture, you can try this:

```
Image image;
BitmapSource bitmapSource = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, dpiWidth, dpiHeight,PixelFormats.Brg32,    null, byteArrayIn, width * PixelFormats.Brg32.BitsPerPixel / 8);
image.Source = bitmapSource;
```

See [BitmapSource.Create()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can also try this:

```
private BitmapImage CreateImage(byte[] imageData)
    {
        if (imageData == null || imageData.Length == 0) return null;
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
        {
            stream.Position = 0;
            image.BeginInit();
            image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.UriSource = null;
            image.StreamSource = stream;
            image.EndInit();
        }
        image.Freeze();
        return image;
    }
```

Comment: So I need to create another variable under my **UserObject** just to store the converted result?

Comment: Yes, of type `Image`.