# Convert a SQL Image to WPF ImageBrush

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I am using Linq-To-Sql to load a SQL image, and I need to convert it to an ImageBrush.ImageSource.

I can't work out how to convert an in-memory image to a URI.

Here's my XAML:

```
<Rectangle Grid.Row="1" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Width="110" Height="80">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="brush" ImageSource="{Binding Picture}"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

And the code-behind:

```
 Dim wpfImage As New Image
 Dim Image As System.Drawing.Image = byteArrayToImage(listOfImage(i).data.ToArray)
 wpfImage.Margin.Top.Equals(th)
 Dim lbl As New Label
 Dim bytBLOBData() As Byte = listOfImage(i).data.ToArray
 wpfImage.Source = BitmapImageFromBytes(bytBLOBData)
```

This is not what I need. I need to get a URI; how can it be accomplished?

Comment: An [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) is ultimately a location somewhere, on your drive or on a network for example. If you absolutely need an URI, you first have to save your image as a file (or have a service that could provide it). So, why do you need an URI for?

Comment: I Am using a template to present the data which requires an ImageBrush! Using the example https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radcarousel/using-radcarousel/carousel-items

Comment: I'd say your problem is the template then; but as I said earlier, you can't convert a byte array to an URI, since an URI needs a physical file (or a file provider).

Comment: Ok thanks I will attempt to change the template.

Comment: Check [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686461/how-do-i-bind-a-byte-array-to-an-image-in-wpf-with-a-value-converter), it could help.

Comment: Thanks Kilazur, That is exactly what I was looking for awesome.

Comment: Ok, I'll mark the question as a duplicate then if you don't mind.

Comment: Hi yes thats fine thanks again.